# How to know what libraries are included in an Android project programmatically?

Tags: android, libraries

I was wondering if it is possible to find all the libraries that are included in the Android project programmatically. I am writing a library which would need info about other libraries included in the project. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: There was a similar question which may be helpful to you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740859/how-to-detect-which-native-shared-libraries-are-loaded-by-android-application

Comment: @mish, that is regarding the system's shared libraries. I need the user added libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made a simple function, just make a call to this function when you want to have the details.

```
public static void checkLibrary(){
            try {
                Log.e(" i am in","checklibrary");
                Set<String> libs = new HashSet<String>();
                String mapsFile = "/proc/" + android.os.Process.myPid() + "/maps";
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mapsFile));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.endsWith(".so")) {
                        int n = line.lastIndexOf(" ");
                        libs.add(line.substring(n + 1));
                    }
                }
                Log.e("Ldd", libs.size() + " libraries:");
                for (String lib : libs) {
                    Log.e("Ldd", lib);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // Do some error handling...
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Do some error handling...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the above method lists all the system libraries. I am looking for the user added libraries into the project. Can i improvise on this solution??

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

You may use Mike Penz's [AboutLibraries](https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries) library

**Benefits**

- Allow to list external, internal libraries used in your project
- Out of box activity or fragment with list of libraries used in your project.