# SDK detection on Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, sdk, detection

I'm currently developing a POC SDK, I need to add an ability to detect if any other 3rd party SDK's (from a finite list) are present on the current App that user my SDK.

For example, detecting that Google maps SDK is being used.

What would be the approaches of doing so on Android and on IOS?

Comment: Maybe you can use something like this : https://github.com/pkumza/LibRadar ?

Comment: That's interesting ... but I would like to do it on my own, preferably in a not obvious way

Comment: Oh, and that is python code. I'm looking for a way to do it with my Android SDK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Android

1. Pick a class from the library and try to load it using a classloader. Advantage: Unlikely to give false positives. Disadvantage: Fails if the class is obfuscated. This means it can only be used reliably on libraries which contain classes which cannot be obfuscated, like activities.
2. Read the apk file and try to find the base package name of the library. Advantage: Doesn't fail on standard-issue proguarded apps. Disadvantage: Analysing classes.dex requires additional tools.
3. Search for the library at compile time (e.g. with a gradle plugin). Advantage: Can plug in before proguard and similar tools. Disadvantage: Is bound to a specific build tool (e.g. gradle).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my goal is to detect if competitor SDK is being used in parallel to my SDK, to avoid customer migration. Is there a more stealth way of doing such task?

Comment: Do you have any direction on IOS too?

Comment: Sorry, no. Although the 3rd way will probably work there too, as almost all toolchains support plugins.

Comment: @RoniGadot: "my goal is to detect if competitor SDK is being used in parallel to my SDK, to avoid customer migration" -- I strongly recommend that you speak to your attorney regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

### IOS

Similar approach can be used for IOS as mentioned by @F43nd1r. Pick a public class and check if that is available or not.

Following is an example for Google Analytics. Google Analytics has a public class called `GAI` ([API Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/reference/interface_g_a_i)). If `GAI` class is available we can assume app is using Google Analytics SDK.

```
if NSClassFromString("GAI") != nil {
    print("App is using Google Analytics SDK")
}
```

### Android

Example for Google Analytics.

```
try {
    if (Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics") != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "App is using Google Analytics SDK");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

Comment: That's a great answer, however @roni asked for a stealthy​ way. This code is obvious and will be detected on a first glance

Comment: Thanks @Bilal, do you think I could use other approach, like maybe monitor the network and find 3rd party end points, to do it in a more subtle and undetected way?

Comment: I don't think you can do networking monitoring in IOS using public APIs. And loading a class using classloader is the most *undetected* way I think (maybe I am wrong).

Answer (score 1):

How about listing at runtime the loaded libraries that the main process is using?

**Advantage:** you should not miss anything by using a deprecated classname or having to know and maintain key methods of each library

**Disadvantage:** you should probably do this periodically, as dynamic loading of libraries is commonplace and the user may have yet to invoke a feature in the app that relies on a given shared library.

### Android

There are 2 ways to do add a dependency to a 3rd party library (SDK).

1. Including the jar as a compiled-in dependency (adding the .jar to the apps libs folder and modifying gradle file)
2. Dynamic loading of native shared library (.so) e.g. via `System.loadLibrary(String)` or `Runtime.getRuntime().load(String)`

To examine the loaded jars, you query the classloader directly:

```
 URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) classloader).getURLs();
 List<String> jars = new ArrayList<>();
 for (URL url : urls) {
     jars.add(url.getFile());
 }
```

Get the classloader from the Thread: `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`

Iterate through the classloader parents until the classloader is `null`.

To list loaded .so libraries you can scan the /proc/your-pid/maps file. See this existing answer for a code snippet. [How to detect which native shared libraries are loaded by Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740859/how-to-detect-which-native-shared-libraries-are-loaded-by-android-application)

Since you are comparing against your own list, the intersection of the two is the answer you are looking at.

```
ArrayList<String> sdkHitlist = myStaticHitList;  //assume populated somewhere
ArrayList<String> currentLibraryList = new ArrayList<String>();

//fill the current list with .jar and .so file strings as above
sdkHitList.retainAll(currentLibraryList);
```