# Android shared library symbol resolution mechanism

Tags: android, shared-libraries, dlopen

With this method [How to detect which native shared libraries are loaded by Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740859/how-to-detect-which-native-shared-libraries-are-loaded-by-android-application)

I found that there are some duplicated library names in the loaded share Libras in an Android application, for example there are:

```
/system/lib64/libhwbinder.so
/system/lib64/vndk-sp-28/libhwbinder.so
```

using

```
nm -D libname
```

the output for the duplicated libraries are exactly the same.

What is the mechanism to decide which symbols to use between the duplicated share library symbols? Answers about Android are preferred since the mechanism may be different than Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is VNDK https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk/, and the mechanism is namespace like:

> The dynamic linker tackles two challenges in Treble VNDK design: SP-HAL shared libraries and their dependencies, including VNDK-SP libraries, are loaded into framework processes. There should be some mechanisms to prevent symbol conflicts.
>
> On the other hand, the linker namespace mechanism provides the
>   flexibility so that some shared libraries may be exported by a linker
>   namespace and used by another linker namespace. These exported shared
>   libraries may become the application programming interfaces that are
>   public to other programs while hiding their implementation details
>   within their linker namespaces.

https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk/linker-namespace.html